# Dynamic array associating a custom field and a name

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

Working with wordpress function.

I have to make a function which is already made with static info, to be dynamic.
I am creating a custom field so that user can insert that info.

I need to pass an array of links associated with a name, which would be perhaps some post name.
The current code has the following structure:

```
function my_function() {
  $First_link = 'http://www.myurl.com.br';
  $Second_link = 'http://www.mysecondurl.com.br';
  ...etc
 
 $allthose_links = array(
   $First_link  => 'First Quiz',
   $Second_link => 'Second Quiz',
  ...etc
 );
 return $allthose_links;
}
```

I need this to be something like:

```
function my_function() {
 $posts = get_posts($args);
 $allthose_links[] = array();
 foreach( $posts as $post ) {
   $thelink = get_field( $post=>['mylink']);
   $thename = $post->name;
 }
    
 $allthose_links = array( //here's the deal
   $thelink   => $thename
  )
    
 return $allthose_links;
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks... I want to fill an array with a name associated with a custom field. Dynamically, as they are inputed through WP dashboard. Later it will be sent to another page. Wisdom has provided a working answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$allthose_link` array should be inside the foreach loop so that each of the links will be added to `$allthose_link` array on every iteration using the link as the key. Your new function should look like the example below:

```
function my_function() {
 $posts = get_posts($args);
 $allthose_links = array();
 foreach( $posts as $post ) {
  $thelink = get_field( $post=>['mylink']);
  $thename = $post->name;
  $allthose_links[$thelink] = $thename;
 }
 return $allthose_links;
}
```